# How to replace an object in a certain context with another object in other context?

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, merge, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've, let's say, a `mainObject` in an `NSManagedObjectContext` in the main queue ("main context"). On the other hand, I've a `privateObject` in another `NSManagedObjectContext` in a private queue ("private context").

I want to delete `mainObject` from maon context, and insert there the `privateObject` in the private context. I tried this:

```
[mainContext insertObject:privateObject];
```

**but I get a crash:**

> 'An NSManagedObject may only be in (or observed by) a single NSManagedObjectContext.'

**I also tried this:**

```
[mainContext objectWithID:privateObject.objectID];
```

and this:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [privateContext existingObjectWithID:privateObject.objectID error:&error];
[mainContext insertObject:managedObject];
```

but I get the same error.

Is there any way to insert an object in a context into another context? Or should I save the private context and then fetch such object from the main context? Or is there another different and better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you should save your child context and after that merge with your parrent context :)

Comment: @MohamadFarhand my contexts don't have a parent/child relationship because I need to create new objects before merging the changes, I can't work with the source objects directly...

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy the object's property?
For example make a new fresh managed object in main context and copy the properties from the private managed object. It would be much clear to understand and would be easily managed.

Comment: The objects I manage have in turn two levels of nested objects, maybe it's not so easy or fast... and I suppose I'll then need to find the way to make a deep-clone of `NSManagedObject`, and I don't know how to handle that, do you know any example/tutorial?